# Is this a React anti-pattern?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I setState to cause a loading spinner to appear and then call a long running operation. The operation blocks the UI, so the spinner doesn't appear. My workaround is to delay the operation by 500ms with setTimeout, so the spinner has time to appear.

Is there a better way?

I even wrote a helper function to do it:

```
  async runAsync(message, asyncFn) {
    const loadingId = this.add(message)
    await _.sleep(50); // Let react update
    await asyncFn();
    this.remove(loadingId)
  }
```

Comment: No, I'd reduce the timeout to 50ms though, that should be enough

Comment: What is the "long running operation" specifically?

Comment: It's a BFS over the values in an MRI. The BFS executes many calls into the Papaya package (google "Papaya MRI")

Comment: There are 256^3 values arranged on the interior points of a cube geometry. The BFS applies a threshold to find the candidate points.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty suspicious for there to be a task that's expensive enough to reliably block rendering on the client. Sometimes a case can be made for it, but in most circumstances there are better approaches.

Ideally, these sorts of expensive operations would be offloaded to your *server* instead, if at all possible. Instead of the client doing it themselves, have the client make a request to the server, have the server perform the work, and then send the result back to the client. (If *you* can easily notice a delay on the computer you use for development, someone opening the website on even worse hardware - such as a phone - would have a much worse experience.)

If the above isn't possible, the other main possibility to consider would be to spawn a separate environment on the client, and perform the work in that environment - which will not interfere with rendering (such as the display of a loading spinner) on the original webpage. This can be accomplished [with a web worker.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). Make a request to the worker while creating the loading spinner, and then the spinner will appear immediately (and animate) while waiting for the worker to finish its processing. Then, have the worker send a message back to the parent page containing the required data.

Comment: My previous solution used a Web Worker actually, but I had to copy a lot of context and business logic over to the worker, and it became a hassle to maintain. I'd need to do an extensive Web Work-ification of an imaging component, which currently performs all its computation in the UI thread.

Comment: I agree with you though; Web Work-ification is the right way to go. I just don't have the time to rewrite this imaging package.